# Nitrous desktop shell becomes unresponsive after a few minutes of idle (windows 8)

Tags: nitrousio

After about 5 minutes after the last command entered the Nitrous Desktop shell no longer accepts any input, although it doesn't seem like the program has crashed as the cursor still blinks.

Opening a new shell works fine, as does using the web ide shell.

I've tested this with several boxes, and it has been the case for several months. I'm now running windows 8.1 but was running windows 7 when I first noticed this.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Well I kind of agree with you - however this is the place that their website http://help.nitrous.io/discussions/ links to for asking support questions, so presumably this is the place I am most likely to get an answer.

SuperUser has no nitrous.io related tags that I can see.

Comment: That's kind of funny in a morbid sort of way. Perhaps you should file a bug report against the Nitrous docs. They clearly should not be pointing folks to Stack Overflow. As you probably know, SO is a programming site for developers. General computer hardware and software support questions are not in SO's charter. Those are probably on-topic for Super User.